# Tutorials on Adobe Gaming SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sdk, adobe

I wanted to learn game development with Adobe Gaming SDK. I have never used any of the tools before but I have good programming experience.

I am confused on how to start learning Adobe Gaming SDK. I couldn't find any tutorials or books on Adobe Gaming SDK. There is lot of information on Flash.

If I start learning Flash will I be learning Adobe Gaming SDK? What’s the difference?

Can anyone tell me, how to start learning Adobe Gaming SDK?

Is there any books or tutorials that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** As of September 2017 (probably earlier) the adobe gaming section of the adobe site appears to be mostly offline/dead. As such archive links have been added alongside the now-dead links.

---

Did you go through the official website. Look here http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/getting-started-games.html
*Link is dead: [Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20170616170442/http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/getting-started-games.html)*

Here's list of SDK s that might be useful for you to get started http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/
*Link is dead: [Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20140614013404/http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/)*

This answers your [Flash](http://www.rivellomultimediaconsulting.com/adobe-game-developer-tools/) question

There are plenty of materials about game development in Flash/Actionscript3, but I would recommend you to learn about a game engine first. It will make your life easier and will help you make a game faster (which will boost your motivation).

Two famous Flash game engines are [Flixel](http://flixel.org) and [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/). Start by checking these [GamedevTuts+](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/) guides: [how to learn Flixel](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn-flixel--gamedev-5843) and [how to learn Starling](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn-starling-framework--gamedev-10760) (there is an article about [how to learn Flash/AS3](http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-learn/how-to-learn-flash-and-as3-for-game-development/) too).

I would recommend you to take a look at [GamedevTuts+](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/). It has several resources about game development, from simple concepts to more advanced things. You will find articles for people with no programming experience at all. It's a great place to start as a novice game developer.

You could also use [Phaser](http://phaser.io) to create your games. It's an easy to learn HTML5 game engine, it doesn't require several tools to develop with (all you need is a code editor and a web server) and your game will run on any modern browser.